# Error con input tipo file con bootstrap y angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Tengo este formulario

```html
<form class="was-validated">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <div class="input-group is-invalid">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="validatedInputGroupSelect">Versiones</label>
      </div>
      <select class="custom-select" id="validatedInputGroupSelect" required>
        <option value="">Elegir...</option>
        <option value="1">3.3</option>
        <option value="2">4.0</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Debes de elegir una versión
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group is-invalid">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="validatedInputGroupCustomFile" required>
      <label for="validatedInputGroupCustomFile" class="custom-file-label">Busca tu archivo...</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Example invalid input group feedback
  </div>
</form>
```

Funciona la primera parte y todo, pero cuando llego a elegir el archivo y lo selecciono queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No muestra el nombre del archivo seleccionado, entonces estuve buscando y el único que me muestra el nombre del archivo, es así:

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Default file input example</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" required>
</div>
```

Cosa que si muestra el nombre del archivo, solo que por estética no se mira bien, entonces quisiera saber como solucionar el que ya esta en el formulario, ya que estoy utilizando bootstrap 4.6 y angular 8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el snippet muestra el botón y el nombre del archivo. Has de tener algo en el `CSS` que oculta los estilos por defecto del `input` de tipo `file`, algo en esta clase `custom-file-input`. Agrega por favor el `CSS` al snippet para tratar de replicar el comportamiento actual del campo y tratar de solucionarlo.

Comment: Lo tome tal cual y el ejemplo de bootstrap no debería tener error, ya que el de abajo que dice default file input example al seleccionar tu archivo claro que si muestra su nombre

Comment: Al editar tu pregunta no usé el código de ejemplo de **Default file input example** en el snippet, sino que utilicé lo que ya nos habías compartido sin `CSS` y muestra el botón y el nombre de archivo. Insisto en que tu código `CSS` debe tener reglas especificas que ocultan los estilos por defecto del `input` de tipo `file` en `custom-file-input` y sin ese código me temo que no hay manera de ayudarte a revisar.